# Как сделать список с уникальными элементами, если в этом списке есть вложенные списки?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List funcForTextField(data, word, image) { //data - список, word - 
строка, image - строка

  List cleanedData = [];
  Set a = {};

  a.add([word, image]);

  for (var i in a) {
    data.add(i);
  }
return data
} //на выходе будет типа [['word', 'image'],['word2', 'image2'],['word3','image3'],['word3','image3'],['word3','image3']], то есть вложенные списки не уникальные, а должны быть уникальными.
```

Из-за вложенных списков этот способ не работает. Не получается создать список с уникальными элементами. Я также пробовал в цикле указывать условие if (data.contains([word,image]) == true){}
но это также не работает.Существует ли какой то способ сделать это?

Comment: Приведите больше данных. Дайте пример входных данных и пример выходных данных. Из вопроса не понятно какой результат вы хотите получить...

Comment: Имеется поиск в flatter(TextField). Есть список экземпляров класса в котором хранятся - название(строка word) и ссылка на картинку (строка image). Если введенное буква-слово в поиске соответствует тому, что есть в списке экземпляров класса, то эти данные word и image отправляются в список. И этот список потом выводится посредством ListView. То есть на выходе указанной мною функции будет [['word, image],[word2, image2],[word3,image3]]. А в ListView будет - Text(forLooter[index][0]) и Image.network( forLooter[index][1])). forLooter - это функция которая в вопросе указана.

Comment: Проблема в том, что на выходе в функции повторяется одно и тоже. То есть я пишу в поиск слово кремль по буквам. Пишу 'к' в список летит кремль и ссылка на картинку, пишу дальше 'р' - в список летит еще кремль с ссылкой, итд. Поэтому мне надо сделать так чтобы в списке не было повторяющихся списков. Потому что в итоге ListView выводит одно и тоже несколько раз

Answer (score 1):

Существует.

Скорее всего нужно использовать сериализацию. Но что и как сериализовать зависит от данных (объема и структуры) и особенностей ЯП (я dart не знаю, гуглить нима желания).

В общем случае алгоритм такой:

- если внутренний список небольшой и слово с картинкой тоже, то тупо перевести в json весь элемент основного списка;
- если список большой или слово+картинка длинная строка, то сериализовать только внутренний список.

Потом создать какую-то ассоциативную структуру куда ключом прописать:

- в первом случае весь джсон в ключ структуры;
- во втором сериализованный внутренний список или слово+картинка, а в значение - список из слова+картинки или сериализованных внутренних списков, соответственно для одинаковых ключей.
  Т.е, должно получиться такое:

```js
1. 
[
  [json(data0, word0, image0)] => '',
  [json(data1, word1, image1)] => '',
  ...
]
2.
[
  [json(data0)] => [word0+image0, word2+image2, ...],
  [json(data1)] => [word1+image1, word3+image3, ...],
  ...
]
3.
[
  [word0+image0] => [json(data0), json(data2), ...],
  [word1+image1] => [json(data1), json(data3), ...],
  ...
]
```

В первом случае уникальность определяется быстро на основании существования/несуществования ключей. Во втором и третьем нужно после создания ассоциативных структур уникализировать списки значений. Ключи, как и в первом случае, создаются уникальными сразу.

Ну и после всего этого пробежаться по структуре, десериализовать/разделить и создать новый список с уникальными значениями.

Варианты с перебором, вложенными циклами, кучей сравнений и поиском внутри структур откидывайте сразу - это тормоз будет.

Надеюсь не сильно мудрено расписал. ))

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:unique_list/unique_list.dart';
/// Create an empty [UniqueList] of [int]s.
final integers = UniqueList<int>();
```

Вместо  укажи свой тип...

https://pub.dev/packages/unique_list

Comment: Это не работает с вложенными списками типа - [['word', 'image'],['word2', 'image2'],['word3','image3'],['word3','image3'] ].

Comment: Потребуется еще переопределить == оператор см https://coflutter.com/dart-how-to-compare-2-objects/

Comment: я просто использовал import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; Для сравнения обычных списков там есть Function eq = const ListEquality().equals;
print(eq([1,'two',3], [1,'two',3])); А для вложенных списков  Function deepEq = const DeepCollectionEquality().equals;
List list1 = [1, ['a',[]], 3];
List list2 = [1, ['a',[]], 3];
print(eq(list1, list2)); // => false
print(deepEq(list1, list2)); // => true

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно что вроде такого:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

const String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
    );

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage();

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final List<UserDetails> _searchResult = <UserDetails>[];
  final List<UserDetails> _userDetails = <UserDetails>[];

  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  // Get json result and convert it to model. Then add
  Future<void> getUserDetails() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
      for (Map user in responseJson) {
        _userDetails.add(UserDetails.fromJson(user));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getUserDetails();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ColoredBox(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  title: TextField(
                    controller: controller,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Search',
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                    onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,
                  ),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                    onPressed: () {
                      controller.clear();
                      onSearchTextChanged('');
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: _searchResult.isNotEmpty || controller.text.isNotEmpty
                ? ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _searchResult.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      return Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              _searchResult[i].profileUrl,
                            ),
                          ),
                          title: Text(_searchResult[i].firstName +
                              ' ' +
                              _searchResult[i].lastName),
                        ),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      );
                    },
                  )
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _userDetails.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              _userDetails[index].profileUrl,
                            ),
                          ),
                          title: Text(_userDetails[index].firstName +
                              ' ' +
                              _userDetails[index].lastName),
                        ),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {
    _searchResult.clear();
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }

    for (UserDetails userDetail in _userDetails) {
      if (userDetail.firstName.contains(text) ||
          userDetail.lastName.contains(text)) _searchResult.add(userDetail);
    }

    setState(() {});
  }
}

class UserDetails {
  final int id;
  final String firstName, lastName, profileUrl;

  UserDetails({
    this.id,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.profileUrl =
        'https://i.amz.mshcdn.com/3NbrfEiECotKyhcUhgPJHbrL7zM=/950x534/filters:quality(90)/2014%2F06%2F02%2Fc0%2Fzuckheadsho.a33d0.jpg',
  });

  factory UserDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserDetails(
      id: json['id'],
      firstName: json['name'],
      lastName: json['username'],
    );
  }
}
```